# My jar file isn't bahaving as it did when I was compiling it as a class file

Tags: jar, console

I wrote a fairly simple piece of code that checks a com port, dumps the stream to a text file (and also to the console) and then sends an email with the String as the body.

Now it all works fine when I'm writing and debugging it but this needs to be a standalone application so I turned it into a jar file.  Now when I run the jar file, a console flashes briefly and disappears and the email does not get sent.  I suspect the com port doesn't get read either.  It just seems to terminate right at the beginning.

I'm sure there's a way around this but to be very specific, what I ultimately need to do is to have this jar file auto-execute on a trigger (probably through windows task assigner) AND for the console to be hidden.  That's the kicker.  I don't know if I can have my cake and eat it too.  I don't want the end user to see the console at all but I want all of the operations to work in the background.  As it stands, the fact that the console dies right away leads me to believe the code isn't even being run.

I'm running this on Windows 7 and it will also have to function on xp.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Open cmd prompt, go to the directory in which you have the jar. run `java -jar <jarname>`. it will show you if there any error.

Comment: The program runs just fine when I do that. It's just when you execute it by double-clicking that it doesn't work properly.